# How do I get a directory from a container down to the travis-ci working directory?

Tags: reactjs, docker, travis-ci, github-pages

I am getting an error when travis-ci builds my app in a docker container.  The build folder is not coming down.Here is the error logs

```
Deploying application
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/d20190115-5107- 
1w5c6ge/work/.git/
Switched to a new branch 'gh-pages'
cd -
cd /tmp/d20190115-5107-1w5c6ge/work
rsync: change_dir "/app/build" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) 
(code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]
Could not copy /app/build.
```

Here are my .travis.yml and dockerfile .

```
# Grants super user permissions
sudo: required

# travis ci installs docker into travis container
services:
  - docker
# before tests are ran build docker image
before_install:
  - docker build -t dvontrec/fn-killers -f Dockerfile.dev .
script:
  # SHOULD ADD TESTS
  - docker run dvontrec/fn-killers pwd
  - docker run dvontrec/fn-killers ls
# Steps before deploy:
defore_deploy:
  - docker run dvontrec/fn-killers -f npm run build
# Steps to deploy to github pages
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github_token: $github_token
  on:
    branch: master
```

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR './app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install 

COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start-docker"]
```

Does anyone know how to get the files down from the container?

Comment: What is the structure of your directory with your `Dockerfile.dev` in it? is there a `./build/` directory in it? You might try adding `RUN mkdir -p /app/build` to the 2nd line of your `Dockerfile.dev` file before `WORKDIR /app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what i did wrong, to deploy with docker you need to have an nginx container that will copy everything down.  Here is the Dockerfile i used.

```
# Build phase
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Run phase
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```